# How to merge left join with two separate names

Tags: pandas

Two data frames df1 and df2

Need to join `user_id` of `df1` with `id` of `df2`

where i will pass `user_id` of `df1` and `id` of `df2`

```
df1.merge(df2, how=left)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='user_id', right_on='id')
```